# why my Metasploit folder does not have wordlists folder (usr/share/)?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, wordlist

I am trying to use msf word-lists but I just noticed in `usr/share/metasploit-framework` there are only two folders `lib` and `config`.

I am not sure how that happened but my msf is updated.

Is there any way to fix this and replace what is missing or get this back to the original state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it there previously?

Comment: Yes, I had the folder structure before.

Comment: I dont see it either, all i see lib

Answer (score 1):

on kali, the standard path for wordlists is `/usr/share/wordlists` - you should find several subfolders there containing wordlists.

Comment: That's for Kali but is not the msf directory structure. The question is asking for the msf resources.

Comment: That's correct but I am wondering why there are folders missing in the `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/` folder. there must be more folders such as `modules`, `vendor`, etc..